# Importing modules correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js

I keep getting this error, are my imports wrong? I've listed my file below

Error:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/server/node_modules/xmlbuilder/lib/XMLDeclaration.js
  Line 20:9:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
```

server.js:

```
require('dotenv').config()
var Flickr = require('flickr-sdk')
var flickr = new Flickr(process.env.FLICKR_API_KEY)

exports.initStream = function() {
  let result
  flickr.photos
    .getRecent()
    .then(function(res) {
      console.log(res.body)
      let result = res.body
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.error('Error: ', err)
    })
  return result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide more information?

- Like the versions of your dependencies
- do you use typescript or something else? (it says Failed to compile)

I tried your code with dotenv 2.0 and flickr-sdk 3.9.0 and i could execute it.

see here https://repl.it/@naxmefy/60336782-importing-modules-correctly